# Is there a time nuance in the second sentence?

Tags: grammar

He didn’t reply even though I sent another email requesting payment.

He didn’t reply, although I sent another email requesting payment.

Comment: The second sentence implies that you sent another email *after* not getting a reply.

Comment: @Esther. I don't quite follow you here. Would there be any other possibility other than "after"? Why send another email if you did indeed receive a reply?

Comment: @PPH The first sentence sounds like the person didn't respond to the *second* email, while in the second sentence the person didn't respond to the *first* email, so the sender sent a second one, with it being implied that having to send a second email in order to get a response is reasonable.

Comment: @Esther. Thank you. It's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is awkward. While it might be spoken the way you have it, it would more likely be written as:

Although I sent another email requesting payment, he didn't reply.

**There is no nuance. The two sentences mean the same thing:**

He didn't reply even though I sent another email requesting payment.